# WordPress V4.3.1, My javascript isn't added to the page when using wp_enqueue_script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, apache

I have a JavaScript file that isn't being loaded and I'm not sure why. I'm customizing a theme (by creating a child theme) in WordPress and I have this functions.php file:

```
<?php

function enqueue_resources()
{
  if (is_page("Projects")) {
       wp_enqueue_script("isotope", "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.2/isotope.pkgd.min.js", array("jquery"));
       wp_enqueue_script("images-loaded", "http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js", array("jquery"));
   wp_enqueue_script("my-script", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/my-script.js", array('jquery', 'isotope', 'images-loaded'), null);


  }
     $parent_style = 'parent-style';
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_resources');
... function to print out currently enqueued scripts/styles
```

And this is the page where I'm trying to enqueue the script: http://dev.presspedal.com/rcnw/projects/ .
I've checked and the correct files/folders exist, the URL generated is correct, the other two scripts are being added to the HTML, no plugins are causing this issue (I deactivated all of them and it's still an issue), `wp_head()`; `wp_footer`; `get_header()`; and `get_footer` are all being called correctly and my-script.js is in the `$wp_scripts->queue`.

But my-script.js isn't being added to the HTML. It's just not there. Here's the weird part: sometimes `my-script.js` is added to my page, but when I clear cache and refresh, it's gone again.

Any help?

Comment: Are you using a child theme?

Comment: Yes I am using a child theme

Comment: try removing the dependancy variables, are you using the pagespeed module?

Comment: The dependency variables have all been removed, no changes. Yes pagespeed is active.

Comment: Since my-script.js was very small, I eventually just manually added a script tag into my template right before I needed the javascript. Didn't fix the issue, but it did make the page display properly.